# How to get the last inserted ID using GORM?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

How to get the value of the Auto increment key for the next record to be inserted? I know how to do it in PHP, but I need to do the same with golang(using gorm) to get the same value so that I can insert the next record properly.

Comment: This isn't a PHP question